# Docker image save tarballs from same Dockerfile with significant different sizes

Tags: image, docker

I have build Docker images on a CentOS 7 (Docker version 1.13.1, build b2f74b2) and a Fedora 29 (v18.09.3) node based on the same Dockerfile and also cross checked that the Dockerfiles have the identical hash

```
sha256sum Dockerfile | cut -b 1-16
38e6a42c5c01a1ac
```

and build the containers with

```
docker build  --build-arg RUN=20190503.centos  -t container:20190503.centos .
```

For comparison/later loading, I saved the images into tarballs.

```
docker save --output /var/tmp/image_20190503.desktop.tar batch:20190503.desktop
```

I would have expected, that the final tarballs should be same in size as they are based on the same Dockerfiles. Bowever, the image tarballs differed significantly

```
container     20190503.desktop    2e3e545f245d        About an hour ago   6.6 GB
container     20190503.centos     afebf959a752        About an hour ago   9.7 GB
-rw------- 1 root root 9,2G May  3 12:44 /var/tmp/container_20190503.centos.tar
-rw------- 1 root root 6,3G May  3 12:53 /var/tmp/container_20190503.desktop.tar
```

(the large size is due to unfortunate 'external' requirements)

(also the size estimation by Docker on the overall layers space seems to be a bit at odds with the final tarballs)

Is there a reason, why Docker image saves should have different sizes when build form the same Dockerfile but on different versions of Docker/OS?

Comment: Different versions of the `FROM` image?  Different external content that gets `COPY`ed into the image?  A large update that got cached in one build but repeated in the other?  All guesses without actually seeing the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi @david-maze  - they should not differ. The Dockerfile and the FROM base image is the same (at least the local image has the same hashes).
All copied files are in a ./root subdir and are identical as far as I see
>  find root/ -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | sort >> /tmp/files.centos

> md5sum /tmp/files.centos /tmp/files.fedora
bc195f81ddf5b8e24f692533f3e002cc  /tmp/files.centos
bc195f81ddf5b8e24f692533f3e002cc  /tmp/files.fedora

Anyway, I have just pruned all images/layers on both nodes and try (hopefully truely) fresh builds

Answer (score 0):

Try using `docker history <image_id>` to see which layers in each build are different sizes.